# Arrow with an asterisk superscript and text above?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, superscripts

I'm trying to create an arrow (or `\mapsto`) that has text above it and also an asterisk superscript — where the asterisk is only a superscript for the arrow, if that makes sense.

I've been trying `\xmapsto{add}^*`; the asterisk seems to be above for the whole thing together, which I think makes sense... but I'm wondering if there's a way I could get the asterisk to just be a superscript to the arrow as if the text wasn't there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your problem is that the argument to the extendible arrow (*e.g.* `add`) is raising the asterisk too high, you can always `\smash` your argument so that it takes no vertical space (*e.g.* using code such as `$\xrightarrow{\smash{add}}^*$`).

**Edit.** As implied by `egreg` in the comments, a better solution would be to use `\xrightarrow{\text{add}}\mathrel{\vphantom{\to}^*}`, so that the text above the arrow contributes to the height of the line without contributing to the height of the superscript. (See [this duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52037/enriching-to) for reference.)

Comment: Incidentally: if you mean for `add` in mathmode to be the English word, then you should probably put it in text-mode, for instance by writing `\xrightarrow{\textit{add}}` or `\xrightarrow{\smash{\textup{add}}}^*` (or the like, where the macros `\text??` are the same macros which modify the typeface in textmode).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much.  I hadn't heard of smash, but it seems that was just what I needed.

Comment: This has the defect that the height of the text over the arrow does not contribute to the height of the line. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52037/enriching-to for a different solution.

Comment: @egreg: good point. I've revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap -- regarding your comment about "add" being an english word, it's more usual (and also somewhat better practice since the term is used in math mode) to use `\mathit` or `\mathrm` rather than a `\text..` command.  in `fontmath.ltx`, the font used for operator names is set by the command `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}`, and `operators` is declared in the same file to be `cmr`; this morphs into `\symoperators` and `\operator@font`, used internally in the definitions for all predefined operator names in latex itself and `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3):

$\stackrel{*}{\to}$ should be something to get you started :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment =) What I'm trying is like, if we had \mapsto^*, how to keep that with the asterisk to the upper right of the arrow-- except for also put text above it..

Comment: Oops, i misunderstood :(  I tried a couple of solutions, but I am not able to do it :(