# Enriching \to^*

Tags: math-mode, arrows, superscripts

I am trying to enrich `$\to^*$` with a `$w$` above it, and the cleanest look I could get was with the `{\smash {\overset w \rightarrow}}^*` command. However, I believe this to be a pretty ugly solution, and `\smash` also smashes the space between two variables and the arrow itself (in for example `$g {\smash {\overset w \rightarrow}}^* g'$`. Is there a better solution that does not result in the `w` to be high above the arrow, or the `*` high above the arrow?

PS: How do you use mathmode or how can you display TeX commands? On other SE sites you can use $ $.

Comment: Regarding your P.S.: You can't, as it's usually the code itself that is interesting. See for example [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths) on meta. You have to upload an image manually.

Comment: How about `$g \mathrel{{\stackrel{\hskip-0.7ex w}{\to}}}{\hskip-1ex}^* g'$`? Also, I really think that it is not LaTeX but it's the notation that makes it uncomfortable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrow with an asterisk superscript and text above?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19071/arrow-with-an-asterisk-superscript-and-text-above)

Comment: I wonder if we should dupe the older question to this one: the solution here looks cleaner to me.

Comment: @JosephWright: It certainly is. As egreg points out, the solution in the other question also gives wrong line height. On the other hand, the other question has a better formulated question text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put a "phantom" arrow; here `\tostar` is defined to have an optional argument, the letter that goes over the arrow (default `w`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\tostar[1][w]{%
  \xrightarrow{#1}\mathrel{\vphantom{\to}^*}
}

\begin{document}
$a \tostar b$
\end{document}
```

We use the fact that TeX doesn't insert spaces between two relation symbols.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This isn't the first time I've seen "phantom". Does it have some meaning?

Comment: The `\vphantom{\to}` only occupies the vertical space of `\to` so we can append the asterisk to the right height.

Comment: Unrelated, but I was wondering why the arrow seems to have some extra stuff in the middle of its shaft. I've seen that strange phenomenon for `\overrightarrow` too. Do you know why?

Comment: @user21820 It's an artifact due to the fact that the arrow is built with a minus sign and an arrow; the PDF viewer must snap both to its grid of pixels and, in some cases, this rounding shows off.

Comment: @egreg: I see, but why is the minus sign needed in the first place? `\to` does not seem to have any minus sign overlaid.